# Populate select dependent dropdowns with cookies in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies

I have built a three tier dependent dropdown in Angular, but I am having trouble populating the values with the saved cookies. Sometimes, all three will populate correctly, and sometimes they just show as a blank string, even 1 or 2 will just populate but not the third. In the HTML code, I have exposed the model in the paragraph tags, so I know the values are being retrieved from cookies, but they are not displaying in the select dropdown. Please forgive any minor errors below.

**Controller**:

```
        angular.module("CountryApp").controller("filterController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies)
        {
            // Getting cookies and trying to assign to models
            $scope.loadCookies = function() {
                var cityCookie = JSON.parse($cookies.get('country'));
                if (cityCookie == null) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    $scope.selectedCountry = JSON.parse($cookies.get('country'));
                    $scope.selectedState = JSON.parse($cookies.get('state'));
                    $scope.selectedCity = cityCookie;
                }
            };

            // When save button is clicked...
            $scope.changedValue = function(country, state, city) {
              $scope.selectedCountry = country;
              $scope.selectedState = state;
              $scope.selectedCity = city;
              // Add to cookies
              $cookies.put('country', JSON.stringify(country));
              $cookies.put('state', JSON.stringify(state));
              $cookies.put('city', JSON.stringify(city));
            };

            $scope.list = [
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'Ohio', 'CITY': 'Cleveland' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'Ohio', 'CITY': 'Columbus' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'Ohio', 'CITY': 'Cincinnati' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'Ohio', 'CITY': 'Akron' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'California', 'CITY': 'Los Angeles' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'California', 'CITY': 'San Diego' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'California', 'CITY': 'San Francisco' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'USA', 'STATE': 'California', 'CITY': 'Santa Monica' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'STATE': 'Alberta', 'CITY': 'Edmonton' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'STATE': 'Alberta', 'CITY': 'Calgary' },
              { 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'STATE': 'British Columbia', 'CITY': 'Victoria' },
               { 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'STATE': 'British Columbia', 'CITY': 'Vancouver' },
            ];
         }]);

         // Custom filter to only return uniques. I put it here just for readability on stackoverflow
         app.filter('unique', function() {
            return function(collection, keyname) {
              // we define our output and keys array;
              var output = [],
                  keys = [];

              angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                  var key = item[keyname];
                  if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                      keys.push(key);
                      output.push(item);
                  }
              });
              return output;
           };
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-init="loadCookies()">
            <div ng-app="CountryApp">
            <select class="form-control" id="country" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="option.COUNTRY for option in list | unique:'COUNTRY'">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
            </select>

            <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" ng-model="selectedState" ng-disabled="!selectedCountry" ng-options="option.STATE for option in list | unique: 'STATE' | filter: { COUNTRY: selectedCountry.COUNTRY }">
                <option value="" disabled selected>State</option>
            </select>

            <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" 
              ng-model="selectedCity" ng-disabled="!selectedArea" 
              ng-options="option.CITY for option in list | unique: 'CITY' |     filter: {STATE: selectedState.STATE, COUNTRY: selectedCountry.COUNTRY}">
              <option value="" disabled selected>City</option>
            </select>


              <p>Selected Country: {{ selectedCountry }} </p>
              <p>Selected State: {{ selectedState }}</p>
              <p>Selected City: {{ selectedCity }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is happening I would look into if they are filtering out each other example if you have Alberta and then USA since when you change one the cookies for Canada might still be set.

Comment: I have seen sometimes where the third dropdown (city) sometimes just selects to a totally random city that I haven't selected or had stored in cookies

Comment: What I am saying is that possibly the ng-options is overriding the selected value. Try without it to see what happens then.

Comment: I've reduced my dropdowns to just one (country), and still about 1/10 times it shows up blank, but if I just print out the cookie it is clearly there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution! Angular didn't like retrieving and setting the cookies with temporary javascript variables. If we switch them to $scope variables, it works great. I also broke it out into a loadCookies function, and assignCookies function.

```
$scope.loadCookies = function() {
    $scope.countryCookie = JSON.parse($cookies.get('country'));
    $scope.stateCookie = JSON.parse($cookies.get('state'));
    $scope.cityCookie = JSON.parse($cookies.get('city'));
};

$scope.assignCookies = function() {
    console.log("assigning");
    if ($scope.cityCookie == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countryCookie;
        $scope.selectedState = $scope.stateCookie;
        $scope.selectedCity = $scope.cityCookie;
    };
};
```